# One overloaded function, yet the program doesn't see it that way

Tags: c++, overloading

The following code has overloaded function **CandyBarFunc**. First prototype defines the function so that it modifies the value of a structure. Second prototype defines the function so that it just displays the content of a passed structure. The problem is that when I run the console program nothing appears on the screen except the Press Any Key...
I tried to debug it and found out that first prototype works properly(I added the display functionality from the second prototype to the first one) becuase it modified and displayed the contents of the structure. So therefore it seems that overloading didn't work because the second function prototype doesn't get called during execution because nothing is displayed on the console screen. I'm not sure if the signaure is bad because the compiler does't complain about the ambigious function call. Did I miss something obvious in the code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct CandyBar
{
    char name[40];
    double weight;
    int calories;
};

void CandyBarFunc(CandyBar & astruct, const char * aname = "Millennium Munch", double aweight = 2.85, int acalories = 350);
void CandyBarFunc(const CandyBar & astruct);

int main(void)
{
    CandyBar MyCandyBar =
    {
        "Hi",
        1.5,
        456
    };
    cout << "1" << endl; 'little debug'
    CandyBarFunc(MyCandyBar); 'suppose to display the contents of MyCandyBar'
    CandyBarFunc(MyCandyBar, "Hello World Candy Bar", 1.25, 200); 'suppose to modify MyCandyBar
    CandyBarFunc(MyCandyBar); 'suppose to display the contents of MyCandyBar again'
    cout << "2"; 'little debug'
    return 0;
}

void CandyBarFunc(CandyBar & astruct, const char * aname, double aweight, int acalories)
{
    strncpy_s(astruct.name,aname,40);
    astruct.weight = aweight;
    astruct.calories = acalories;
    cout << "Name: " << astruct.name << endl; 'not suppose to be here, just for debug'
    cout << "Weight: " << astruct.weight << endl; 'not suppose to be here, just for _ debug'
    cout << "Calories: " << astruct.calories; 'not suppose to be here, just for debug'
}

void CandyBarFunc(const CandyBar & astruct)
{
    cout << "Name: " << astruct.name << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << astruct.weight << endl;
    cout << "Calories: " << astruct.calories;
}
```

Exercise:

> The CandyBar structure contains three members. The first member holds the brand
>   name of a candy bar. The second member holds the weight (which may have a fractional
>   part) of the candy bar, and the third member holds the number of calories (an integer
>   value) in the candy bar. Write a program that uses a function that takes as arguments a
>   reference to CandyBar, a pointer-to-char, a double, and an int and uses the last three
>   values to set the corresponding members of the structure. The last three arguments
>   should have default values of “Millennium Munch,” 2.85, and 350. Also, the program
>   should use a function that takes a reference to a CandyBar as an argument and displays
>   the contents of the structure. Use const where appropriate.

Comment: Where exactly does the exercise say that both functions must have the same name?

Answer (score 4):

Since `MyCandyBar` isn't const, the compiler choses the first (reference to non-const) overload.

But seriously, if you want one function to set properties and another function to print them out, *please* don't abuse overloading by giving them the same name. Just name them differently, no more problems.

Also, in C++ we prefer `std::string` to fixed-size character arrays and character pointers.

Comment: All that is great advice Fred, but it's not my choice if I use overloading in this case or char instead of string. I would if the book that I'm reading on my own would instruct me so in the Programming Exercises section. I've posted the exercise in my original post. Did I misunderstood something in that exercise? Also I hope it's ok if I quote a part of the book online. Also I guessed that it's the const problem but doesn't that const just means that the passed argument won't be modified?

Comment: @Bill: What is the name of that book? I am asking because there are tons of books on C++ out there that would serve better as toilet paper than as learning material.

Comment: @Bill It is true that const says that the parameter will not be modified, but if you have two overloads which differs in const only (bad idea) and one of those is an exact match for the parameter, that little difference will be the tie breaker in overload resolution. An exact match is just better.

Answer (score 0):

Since MyCandyBar is not const, it will always try to use the function which accepts the non const CandyBar. You can force it to call the other function by casting it to const:

```
CandyBarFunc((const CandyBar &)MyCandyBar);
```